# Extract data from api using shell scripting

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl, jq

So we have many vlans at work, often it is nice to see which ip ranges are associated with said vlan. We have a well developed api for displaying information about our network and thus I wrote a small script to extract this information.

The only issue is that to access the API we require a token, no older than X hours. So, the script both need to check this token, and renew it if need be, before running the command.

The API is not public but the response data looks like

#### Query

```
v1/networks/?vlan=119
```

#### Response

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 13,
      "excluded_ranges": [],
      "created_at": "2019-10-16T14:57:55.932564+02:00",
      "updated_at": "2019-10-23T12:23:30.914823+02:00",
      "network": "yyy.xxx.2.64/27",
      "description": "core-3",
      "vlan": 119,
      "dns_delegated": false,
      "category": "so",
      "location": "",
      "frozen": false,
      "reserved": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 1110,
      "excluded_ranges": [],
      "created_at": "2019-10-16T14:57:55.932564+02:00",
      "updated_at": "2019-10-10T12:44:18.912178+02:00",
      "network": "xxx:yyy:zzz:540::/64",
      "description": "core-3",
      "vlan": 119,
      "dns_delegated": false,
      "category": "",
      "location": "",
      "frozen": false,
      "reserved": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

The code is used as `./ulan.sh 119` with response

```
yyy.xxx.2.64/27       core-3
xxx:yyy:zzz:540::/64  core-3
```

The code works as intended, it passes shellcheck and is formated using `shfmt -l -w -i 4 ulan.sh`. However, I feel there is still much to be improved.

Full code

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Author: Nebuchadnezzar
#
# License: GPLv3+

# Set PATH
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH

# Usage
usage=$(
    cat <<-EOF
$(basename "$0") [-h]

List ip-range and description associated with the uio drifted vlan

where:
    -h,  --help                     show this help text

examples:
  command:
    ulan 119

  ouput:
    yyy.xxx.2.64/27       core-3
    xxx:yyy:zzz:540::/64  core-3
EOF
)

# If no arguments display usage
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo >&2 "$usage"
    exit 1
fi

# Help
if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    echo "$usage"
    exit 0
fi

MREG_TOKEN_PATH="$HOME/.mreg-cli_auth_token"
MREG_VERSION="1"
MREG_API="https://mreg.uio.no/api"
VLAN=$1

function create_mreg_token {
    echo "Connecting to https://mreg.uio.no"
    printf "Username: " >&2
    read -r USER
    printf 'Password for %s:' "$USER"
    trap 'stty echo' INT EXIT
    stty -echo
    read -r MYPASS
    printf "\n"
    token_object=$(
        curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --silent \
            --data "{\"username\":\"$USER\",\"password\":\"$MYPASS\"}" \
            "${MREG_API}/token-auth/"
    )
    token=$(echo "$token_object" | jq -r '.token')
    echo -n "$USER¤$token" >"$MREG_TOKEN_PATH"
}

function check_vlan {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No arguments supplied"
        exit 1
    fi
    vlan="$1"
    if [ ! -f "$MREG_TOKEN_PATH" ]; then
        touch "$MREG_TOKEN_PATH"
    fi
    mreg_token=$(cut -d "¤" -f2 "$MREG_TOKEN_PATH")
    mreg_query="${MREG_API}/v${MREG_VERSION}/networks/?vlan=$vlan"
    mreg_response_http_code=$(
        curl \
            --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output /dev/null \
            -s -H "Authorization: Token ${mreg_token}" \
            "${mreg_query}"
    )
    if [ "$mreg_response_http_code" -ne 200 ]; then
        echo "Invalid mreg token! Creating.."
        create_mreg_token
        mreg_token=$(cut -d "¤" -f2 "$MREG_TOKEN_PATH")
    fi
    mreg_response=$(
        curl -s -H "Authorization: Token ${mreg_token}" \ 
        "$mreg_query"
    )
    result=$(echo "$mreg_response" | jq -c .results)
    for row in $(echo "${result}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
        _jq() {
            echo "${row}" | base64 --decode | jq -r "${1}"
        }
        echo "$(_jq '.network') $(_jq '.description')"
    done | column -t
}

check_vlan "${VLAN}"
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Improve the validation of command line arguments

The condition means "the first argument is not empty",
but the comment says something else, which is confusing:

> ```
> # If no arguments display usage
> if [ -z "$1" ]; then
> ```

It would be better to fix the condition (as you did elsewhere already):

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
```

Keep in mind that this changes the behavior of the program,
because now the condition will let through invocations with an empty first argument.

I think a good solution will be to make the input validation stronger,
and ensure that the VLAN argument is actually an integer:

```
if ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
   echo >&2 "error: VLAN must be a positive integer; got $1"
   exit 1
fi
```

If there is a valid range of numbers, then you might want to add another condition to validate that too.

Finally, I would put `VLAN=$1` right after the input validation,
while the meaning of `$1` is the most fresh in the reader's head.

#### Improve the usage message

The first line of the usage message is:

> ```
> $(basename "$0") [-h]
> ```

It doesn't mention that a VLAN parameter is required.
It would be better to add VLAN on that line,
and in the description clarify the expected values.

Later the example text says:

> ```
> examples:
>   command:
>     ulan 119
> ```

There the use of literal "ulan" can be different from `$(basename "$0")` earlier above.
This can be confusing, and it would be good to avoid by using the same expression,
a variable in both places, which stores the output of `$(basename "$0")`.

#### Avoid running programs in a loop

Executing commands in a loop can be costly,
because of the overhead of running a process.
So it's good to look for opportunities to avoid that.

Instead of this:

> ```
> result=$(echo "$mreg_response" | jq -c .results)
> for row in $(echo "${result}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
>     _jq() {
>         echo "${row}" | base64 --decode | jq -r "${1}"
>     }
>     echo "$(_jq '.network') $(_jq '.description')"
> done | column -t
> ```

You can write simpler and faster as:

```
jq -r '.results[] | (.network + " " + .description)' <<< "$mreg_response" | column -t
```

#### Consider validating required non-standard commands

`jq` is not a program that's generally installed by default in operating systems.
It's good to add a check and fail early in the script if the program is missing.

#### Avoid unnecessary HTTP calls

When the file `$MREG_TOKEN_PATH` does not exist,
this code creates an empty file,
reads from it, and makes an HTTP call:

> ```
> if [ ! -f "$MREG_TOKEN_PATH" ]; then
>     touch "$MREG_TOKEN_PATH"
> fi
> mreg_token=$(cut -d "¤" -f2 "$MREG_TOKEN_PATH")
> mreg_query="${MREG_API}/v${MREG_VERSION}/networks/?vlan=$vlan"
> mreg_response_http_code=$(
>     curl \
>         --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output /dev/null \
>         -s -H "Authorization: Token ${mreg_token}" \
>         "${mreg_query}"
> )
> ```

Can that HTTP call ever succeed with an empty token?
If not, then I suggest to rework the code accordingly.

#### Add error handling for `create_mreg_token`

`check_vlan` calls this function,
and assumes that it successfully created a token,
but that's not guaranteed.

A better solution would be for `create_mreg_token` to raise an error if it could not create a token and exit.

Also, it could echo the token, so that `check_vlan` could use the output, rather than parsing the password file.

#### Simplify reading input using builtin features of `read`

Instead of printing a prompt with `printf "Username: "`,
you can use `read -p "Username: " username`.

To avoid echoing the password as the user types, you can use the `-s` flag:

```
read -sp "Password: " password
```

#### Write actionable error messages

In this code:

> ```
> if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
>     echo "No arguments supplied"
>     exit 1
> fi
> ```

The error message *implies* that there must be some arguments,
but it doesn't make it clear enough what is expected.

#### Print error messages on `stderr` consistently

In some places the program prints error messages on `stdout`, for example here:

> ```
> if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
>     echo "No arguments supplied"
>     exit 1
> fi
> ```

It would be good to make that consistent.

#### Consider not storing the username at all

`create_mreg_token` reads the username from `stdin`,
makes an HTTP call to get a token,
stores the username and the token in a file.

`check_vlan` extracts the token from the file,
and disregards the username.

If the username is not needed outside this script,
then no need to store it,
and the script can be a bit simpler.

(The next two sections of this review only arise because of the added complexity of storing the username.)

#### Use a constant for separator characters

One part of the code creates a file with a field separator:

> ```
> echo -n "$USER¤$token" >"$MREG_TOKEN_PATH"
> ```

Another part of the code reads from that file, expecting the same separator:

> ```
> mreg_token=$(cut -d "¤" -f2 "$MREG_TOKEN_PATH")
> ```

It would be good to put the separator in a constant,
that way the reader can be sure that different parts of the code will use the same value.

#### Avoid unreadable characters in scripts when possible

This command uses an unreadable separator character:

> ```
> echo -n "$USER¤$token" >"$MREG_TOKEN_PATH"
> ```

I would like to be able to copy-paste script snippets correctly,
but if I cannot read a character I'm not confident it comes out correctly.

#### Use lowercase variable names for local variables

Local variables in functions should be declared using the `local` keyword,
to avoid accidental reading or writing to global variables,
and lowercase naming is recommended.

#### Use modern style function declaration

Instead of:

> ```
> function foo {
> ```

The preferred form is:

```
foo() {
```

#### Use more blank lines

The two functions in the posted code do multiple logical steps,
and have no blank lines.
This makes them a bit difficult to read.
Consider adding some blank lines,
like you did in the read of the code.

#### Avoid unnecessary comments

These comments in this code don't add value, I suggest to delete them:

> ```
> # Set PATH
> PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
> export PATH
>
> # Usage
> usage=$(...)
>
> # If no arguments display usage
> if [ -z "$1" ]; then
>     ...
>
> # Help
> if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
>     ...
> ```

#### Don't use `echo` if you need to use any flags

The flags of `echo` such as `-n` and `-e` don't work reliably in all systems.
It's better to avoid using them.

The script uses `echo -n` in one place,
and you can safely drop the `-n` without changing the behavior.
If for some reason outside this script it's important to not write a terminating newline, then use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

@janos has already given great feedback that covers basically everything I would say and more when it comes to the shell script. I'd only add suggestions to factor out the error exits into a function (DRY), and to consider `[[ test ]] && function` (or `||`) for asserts, and to think about what should be going to stdout and stderr (and why).

I do, however, want to raise a very different suggestion; shell scripts are not great for interfacing with neither APIs nor with JSON data, so maybe consider a different language? If you went for, for example, python, it'd give you improvements e.g. with argument handling, query parameters, testability, and would have native support for interfacing with JSON.